# How to migrate a data base from mysql to postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a file .sql and I can't open it with pgadmin.
How do I import it?

Comment: [MySql to PostgreSql migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756825/mysql-to-postgresql-migration)

Comment: [Switching from MySQL to PostgreSQL - tips, tricks and gotchas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772111/switching-from-mysql-to-postgresql-tips-tricks-and-gotchas)

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL wiki has a lot of interesting links for exactly this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL