# python - putting mysql records/rows into dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, dictionary, database-migration

Our team is working on a new version of a webapp. One of the main difference from the old version is the DBMS used. The backed designers decided to skip from mysql to postgresql. In addition to this, also the db structure/schema is been renewed.

I'm starting to work on a python script that will take care to migrate the data of "old" customers.

(Q) My main question is Am I choosing the right approach to solve this problem?

**The "big picture" of the plan (not that big I know) is as follow:**

- installing python and dependencies on customer server.
- mysql will be already present on the server since required from the old webapp
- installing postgresql and create the new database with its empty structure
- run the python script.

**The python script will take care of the following operations:**

- open connections with both DBMS
- select certain kind of data from mysql, and put each row into a dictionary
- process/manipulate the data, in order to make it compatible with the new database
- insert the fixed data into postgresql database

(Q) My second question is Are python dictionaries a suitable data structure to do what I'm trying to do?

Unfortunately I'm already stuck at the second/third bullet point ("put each mysql row into a dictionary & manipulate data"). My script currently look as follow (my python is not that good I know :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# ------------------------------
# import of standard libraries |
# ------------------------------
#
import os
import sys
import mysql.connector
import psycopg2
from pprint import pprint
import MySQLdb

# ------------------------------
# import of internal snippets  |
# ------------------------------
#
from include.db_config import *
#from include.MySQLCursorDict import *

# ------------------------------
# Community Migration          |
# ------------------------------
#
cnx = mysql.connector.connect( host=host_mysql, user=user_mysql, passwd=pswd_mysql, db=dbna_mysql )
cur = cnx.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * from elements where type=1")

result = []
columns = tuple( [d[0].decode('utf8') for d in cur.description] )

for row in cur:
  result.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

pprint(result)

cur.close()
cnx.close()
```

the problem is that I'm really not sure that I obtain a real dictionary with this code, since I'm not having success manipulating the data (e.g. change the column name) P.S.: the keys of the dict are the column names in mysql record, all the values are the fields.

(Q) Does anybody know the correct way to put mysql records in a dictionary in order to be able to "comfortably" manipulate it?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help

Comment: About your big picture. Are you going to stop/disable write operations through old application, while doing migration? If not there is possible a situation, when new data is created and saved into MySQL during migration process, but won't be migrated to PostgreSQL.

Comment: If you have a lot of data, processing them row by row is going to take a long long time. Why don't you first try dump and import and try scripts only if it doesn't work? You can of course work on the dumped data before importing it back into postgresql

Comment: @ Yaroslav Admin : well pointed out, thank you! Probably I will completely disable the access to the webapp during the migration. You right I must add this important step to the big picture

Comment: @  e4c5 : I had not think about the performance until now, you right it must be taken in consideration. I have just retrieved some information about that, and the biggest database I have to migrate is not that big: about 100/200GB. I see it very difficult to process the dump.sql in order to make it compatible with the new database structure/schema, anyway I think your Idea is a good hint [continue...]

Comment: [...] because maybe I could mysqldump in some format that is easy to put into python dictionaries, like XML or CSV, and then iteratively process each statement. Something similar as what Maxim Sloyko suggest in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756825/mysql-to-postgresql-migration